# Twitter GEM for API not working on site, but in console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I'm using sferik's amazing Twitter gem: https://github.com/sferik/twitter.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
twitter_api = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "123"
  config.consumer_secret     = "123"
  config.access_token        = "123"
  config.access_token_secret = "123"
end
```

And when I boot up the terminal, and do `twitter_api` I get:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `twitter_api' for main:Object
```

BUT when I manually enter the code as:

```
1.9.3-p448 :002 > twitter_api = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
1.9.3-p448 :003 >   config.consumer_key        = "123"
1.9.3-p448 :004?>   config.consumer_secret     = "123"
1.9.3-p448 :005?>   config.access_token        = "123"
1.9.3-p448 :006?>   config.access_token_secret = "123"
1.9.3-p448 :007?> end
```

And the `twitter_api` give me a value and I when I do a simple get request:

```
1.9.3-p448 :009 > twitter_api.user("BenMorganIO")
 => #<Twitter::User id=2224124594>
```

So I know that the authentication is Okay, I just can't seem to get it working on the site.

I've placed the config code within `config/initializers/twitter.rb`

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `twitter_api` variable is declared as a **local** variable, so you cannot access from outside of this class. What I guess you want is a [global](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/globalvars.html) `$twitter_api` variable.